# SCHEME - Writing my own append produces a weird result

Tags: list, functional-programming, append, scheme, r5rs

I want to write my own append , for appending an element to an existing list .

I've written the following :

```
(define (appendElem llist elem)
    (if (null? llist)
        elem
        (cons (car llist) (appendElem (cdr llist) elem))))
```

But when I do this :

```
(appendElem (list 1 2 30) 11)
```

I get :

```
(1 2 30 . 11)
```

So the question is , why `(1 2 30 . 11)` and not `(1 2 30 11)` ?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Fixed :

```
(define (appendElem llist elem)
    (if (null? llist)
        (list elem)
        (cons (car llist) (appendElem (cdr llist) elem))))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think about what you want your base case to be. Do you want just `elem`, or do you want a *list* with the single item `elem`? There is a difference. If the want the latter, you will need to fix your base case in the code.

In other words, do you want `(appendElem '() 42)` to return `42`, or `(42)`? Think carefully about the answer to that question, then think about what the consequence of each choice is.

By the way, while you can implement `appendElem` as a toy, you'll soon realise that that function has O(n) runtime. So do not build lists using this approach! The standard way to build a list is to `cons` items to it, then `reverse` the final resulting list.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer :

```
(define (appendElem llist elem)
    (if (null? llist)
        (list elem)
        (cons (car llist) (appendElem (cdr llist) elem))))
```

Thanks to @Chris Jester-Young .

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion for you:

```
(define (make-dl ls)      ; turn a list into a difference list
  (cons ls (last-pair ls)))

(define (snoc-dl! dl e)   ; snoc ~ appendElem, destructively
  (set-cdr! (cdr dl) (list e))
  (set-cdr! dl (cddr dl)))

(define (dl-list dl)      ; get the list back
  (car dl))
```

for an `O(1)` appending at list's end (well, calling `make-dl` will be `O(n)`, but all the subsequent appends will take `O(1)` time).