# Scheme task decomposition - global variable issues

Tags: list, variables, scheme

So here is my problem (generalized to an abstract situation). It is generally an interpreter.

I have got a program that needs to parse an input list and according to its elements sequentially call some functions that need to modify variables. Functions are defined separately and chosen by **(cond** . Those 3 variables that I need to update contain information about current situation (exactly - robot position, maze and robot orientation). The result of previous function is used in the next function (i.e. the updated variables are used).

```
(define func-a ... )
(define func-b ... )

(define (main-func <maze> <orientation> <coordinates> <list with commands>)

  ;; here I parse the list and choose which function to call
  ;; output must contain (list <new-maze> <new-orientation> <new-coordinates>))

)
```

What scheme tools can I use to update those variables? I have considered several options:

- use (define and then call set! (this is bad style cause it is not pure functional programming);
- call functions from back to beginning (this won't work: I also have to check if movement is valid);
- don't make those variables constant at all, try passing them as arguments to each function;

Is there any other proper way to do it?

Comment: I think, you need to be more specific. The way always depends on the problem, and the amount of information, you gave, is insufficient.

Comment: I'd go with your 3rd option, passing along the triple of vars (representing the state) from function into another function (preferably, in a tail call). You could also collect those triples into a list as you update them, thus creating an explicit history of evaluation (might be useful if your robot were trying to solve the maze) - grow the list e.g. [like here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14965347/849891).

Comment: If you persist down this dark and winding path of trying to remain purely functional while dealing with state, you will eventually come into the kingdom of the monads. http://www.cs.indiana.edu/cgi-pub/c311/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=manymonads.pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep some state (as well as read a file), so there will not be a pure functional programming, and you have to accept some deviations.

The general approach is to keep the shared object as a local in some meta-function, say `parse`, and update it by calling those your function, say `parse-one`, `parse-two`, and so on.

Now you need a way to update them.

You can make them visible for `parse-one` and `parse-two` by defining them inside the scope:

```
(let ((state (make-state)))
  (let ((parse-one (lambda () ...))
        (parse-two (lambda () ...)))
    ....))
```

Or you use the return value:

```
(let ((state (make-state)))
  ...
  (set! state (parse-one state))
  ...)
```

There is a third approach, called OOP. Define all of them in a single closure, so they can share some data:

```
(define (make-parser)
  (let ((state (make-state))
    (let (((parse-one (lambda () ...))
          ((parse-two (lambda () ...))
          ((get-state (lambda () state)))
       (list parse-one parse-two get-state))))

(destructuring-bind (parse-one parse-two get-state) (make-parser)
  ...
  (parse-one)
  ...
  (get-state))
```

([destructuring-bind](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_destru.htm) is just an easy way to destruct a list, see it's [scheme implementation](http://pschombe.wordpress.com/2006/03/10/destructuring-bind/)) But it seems to be a complicated version of the first.

Answer (score 1):

Just because Scheme is considered a 'functional language' doesn't forbid you from using 'set!' - after all it exists in the language to be used.  Thus there is nothing wrong with:

```
(define-record-type position (fields x y z))

(define robot-position (make-position 0.0 0.0 0.0))

(define update-robot-position (new-x new-y new-z)
  (set! robot-position (make-position new-x new-y new-x)))
```

[I've chosen to define positions as invariant.]

You can chose another approach if you want but fundamentally the position of the robot changed and that change will be in your code is some fashion.  Why not use the simplest, most straight-forward approach?